# how to create a stored procedure in oracle which accepts array of parameters

Tags: oracle, arrays, stored-procedures

Can any one tell me if its possible to create a stored procedure in oracle which accept array as an input parameter and how ?

Comment: What kind of client do you have? Do you want to call this stored procedure from another pl/sql procedure or from C# or Java or ...?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.  Oracle calls them collections and there's a variety of collections you can use.

A simple array example using a VARRAY.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE Str_Array IS VARRAY(4) OF VARCHAR2(50);
  v_array  Str_Array;

  PROCEDURE PROCESS_ARRAY(v_str_array  Str_Array)
  AS
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN v_str_array.first .. v_str_array.last LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello '||v_str_array(i));
    END LOOP;
  END;

BEGIN

  v_array := Str_Array('John','Paul','Ringo','George');

  PROCESS_ARRAY(v_array);

  -- can also pass unbound Str_Array
  PROCESS_ARRAY(Str_Array('John','Paul','Ringo','George'));

END;
```

Comment: very excellent.  I added a second example showing Str_Array(...) as the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, there's a native type called TABLE that basically is an array. But last time I used it was 2001 so maybe there are most powerful types nowadays.

Check this http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3379271