# Passing an array from .Net application to Oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to pass an array from C#.net application to oracle stored procedure.
Can anyone please let me know how to go about it?
Also, which OracleType type do I use in C# when passing input parameter to stored procedure?

FYI, am using System.Data.OracleClient in my C# app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jimmy,
the System.Data.OracleClient does not support arrays.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/57a59fba-09e2-46cb-a072-6706b3ec5131

Depending on your need, you will either need to implement this via nested table types (via UDTs or assoc. arrays) using the ODP.net clients.   This is probably a good direction to go, esp. since .net 4.0 has [deprecated System.Data.OracleClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/system-data-oracleclient-update).

But if you are stuck with the System.Data.OracleClient and you are really just trying to do a variable in-list, you can do this by passing in a string and following some of these suggestions:
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You should use DB-defined nested table types to pass an array to PL/SQL. Take a look at [this nice tutorial](http://my-tech-talk.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-pass-arrays-from-net-c-to-oracle.html), it might help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but this approach requires Oracle .NET driver Oracle.DataAccess whereas I'm using Microsoft System.Data.OracleClient.

Comment: @Jimmy Hello. I'm beg my pardon, I was inattentive. Must admit that I don't know how to solve your issue with System.Data.OracleClient :)

Comment: It'd be best to switch to the Oracle drivers. More features, and they'll be supported out in to the future. Here's another example of a procedure that accepts an array. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831188/how-to-create-a-stored-procedure-in-oracle-which-accepts-array-of-parameters)