# creating a procedure for nested tables

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

The following codes successfully creates a procedure using sql*plus

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE input_order (pat_id in char, vis_vdate in date, vis_act in number,  
 vac_vacc in char)
AS
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert attempted');
insert into vaccinations(pid,vdate,action,vaccinated) values(pat_id,vis_vdate,vis_act,vac_vacc);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert succeeded');
EXCEPTION
WHEN others THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('error');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert rejected');
END;
/
```

However my intension is to create a similar procedure which includes populating a nested table as  an attribute of a table

- for example: supposing 'vis_act' is a nested table
- with type vis_set_t
- and attributes visname and visurname

i tried it this way but kept getting errors

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE input_order (pat_id in char, vis_vdate in date, vis_act in 
vis_set_t, vac_vacc in char)
AS
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert attempted');
insert into vaccinations(pid,vdate,vis_set_t(visname,visurname),vaccinated) values
(pat_id,vis_vdate,vis_act,vac_vacc);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert succeeded');
EXCEPTION
WHEN others THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('error');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert rejected');
END;
/
```

Comment: Good example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831188/how-to-create-a-stored-procedure-in-oracle-which-accepts-array-of-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General insert example. 
As I mentioned in comments I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish in your procedure. This is general insert example. Feel free to ask more questions...:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE EmpTabTyp IS TABLE OF scott.emp%ROWTYPE;
  emp_tab EmpTabTyp:= EmpTabTyp();
--
PROCEDURE insert_emp(p_col_typ IN EmpTabTyp) 
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO emp_tab FROM scott.emp;
--
  FOR i IN p_col_typ.first .. p_col_typ.last 
  LOOP
    -- Insert your values into your table --
    INSERT Into emp_test (empno, ename) VALUES (p_col_typ(i).empno, p_col_typ(i).ename);

  -- Optionally display values inserted - do not do this if table has many rows --
  --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('INSERTED :'|| p_col_typ(i).empno||chr(9)||p_col_typ(i).ename);
   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Total rows inserted :'||p_col_typ.Count);
 END insert_emp;
BEGIN
  insert_emp(emp_tab);
END;
/
```

In addition to my comment above:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE EmpTabTyp IS TABLE OF scott.emp%ROWTYPE;
  emp_tab EmpTabTyp:= EmpTabTyp();
PROCEDURE display_emp (p_col_typ IN EmpTabTyp) 
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO emp_tab FROM scott.emp;
--
  FOR i IN p_col_typ.first .. p_col_typ.last LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(p_col_typ(i).empno||chr(9)||p_col_typ(i).ename);
  END LOOP;
 END display_emp;
BEGIN
  display_emp(emp_tab);
END;
/

DECLARE
  l_names   DBMS_UTILITY.maxname_array; -- or DBMS_UTILITY.name_array
PROCEDURE show_contents (names_in IN DBMS_UTILITY.maxname_array)
IS
BEGIN
  FOR indx IN names_in.FIRST .. names_in.LAST
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (names_in (indx));
  END LOOP;
END;
BEGIN
  l_names (1) := 'Picasso';
  l_names (2) := 'Keefe'; 
  l_names (3) := 'Dali';
  show_contents (l_names);
END;
/

-- returning collection type example:
DECLARE
  TYPE t_emptbl IS TABLE OF scott.emp%rowtype;
  v_emptbl t_emptbl; 
  ret_val  t_emptbl; 
Function getEmployeeList Return t_emptbl 
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT * bulk collect INTO v_emptbl FROM scott.emp;
  -- Print nested table of records:
  FOR i IN 1 .. v_emptbl.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_emptbl(i).empno);
  END LOOP;
 RETURN v_emptbl;
END;
BEGIN
  ret_val:= getEmployeeList;
END;
/
```

Comment: @ Art, i do not understand the way you did it but i have updated my question with the approach i used which didnt work

Comment: @Lee, my examples are general ones. I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish by using nested table in your procedure.To insert values in some table you do not really need a nested table in your procedure.  It would be much easier to understand of you add create table/insert scrips etc... I'll try to find insert example with nested tables for you. But it will be general example based on scott.emp table...