# Pass an array of object to Stored procedure with Oracle ManagedDataAccess.dll

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle12c, odp.net, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am upgrading my application to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess. I want to pass an array of objects to a stored procedure.

Following is my SP:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MATCHING_CRITERIA_LIST IS TABLE OF CRITERIA;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_FILTERED_EMPLOYEE (
IN_CRITERIA_LIST   IN       MATCHING_CRITERIA_LIST,
CUR_OUT            OUT      sys_refcursor
)
AS
OPEN CUR_OUT FOR
--My Select Query--
END;
```

I am trying to execute SP through C# .NET, and getting error.

```
var param = new OracleParameter() { ParameterName = "IN_CRITERIA_LIST", Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray, DbType = DbType.Object}; 
param.Value = /*Some Array */;
var parameters = new List<IDbDataParameter>() {param, new OracleParameter("CUR_OUT", OracleDbType.RefCursor) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output }};
reader = dbConn.ExecuteReaderWithParams("GET_FILTERED_EMPLOYEE", parameters, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Error:

> Message=Unsupported column datatype
>   Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver

This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917482/pass-array-to-stored-procedure) as I am trying to pass an array of user defined object and not primitive types.

Comment: No it isnot a duplicate. I am trying to pass array of Objects. The link you shared is of passing array of strings/int. The above code works for me in case of int, but not when I pass an array of class object.